# Custom UIButton that generates UIView in SuperView

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uibutton

I'm experimenting a custom class button that display the UIView when touch start.
I have a UIButton class name it TapInButton. here're codes.

```
#import "TapInButton.h"
#import "TapInViewController.h"

@interface TapInButton()
@property (nonatomic,strong) TapInViewController * tapIn;
@end
@implementation TapInButton
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    
    self.tapIn = [[TapInViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TapIn" bundle:nil];
    self.tapIn.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 50, 300, 500);
    self.tapIn.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    
    [self.superview addSubview:self.tapIn.view];

    
}
```

As you can see, I import TapInViewController that generates xib file.
When the user click the tapin button that has a custom class TapInButton.
It Display the xib file. see image below
[image]

I successfully add the xib to the main ViewController but the problem is I cannot click the button inside the xib file. Is there something missing in my code? or Is this possible to generate a uiview inside a custom UIButton?

I know the other way to generate a xib file but not using custom button. I just want to clarify my mind if this is possible. Hoping for your advice or explanation. Thanks in advance

Comment: do you have userInteractionEnabled?

Comment: also I am not sure if this is completely necessary but you usually call [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent: event]; at the beginning of the method.

Comment: @JoshGafni sorry late reply. I'm just guessing if that work. I'm new of this custom class. I try to enable the userInteractionEnable but the same output. I can't click the button inside my xib file.

Answer (score 0):

> the problem is I connot click the button inside the xib file. Is there something missing in my code?

You'll have to obtain a reference to the button in code and set up the button-click action connection in code (by calling `addTarget:action:forControlEvents:`).

Comment: sorry late reply. I try it in TapInViewController and add the addTarget:action:forControlEvents: in viewdidload but it doesn't work.